# How to make a mesh (obj file) a solid on Python?

Tags: python, mesh, 3d-printing, pyvista

I've been working with pyvista on Python to filter a scan of my arm, obtaining an obj object in the end. But everytime I try to open the final result on SolidWorks it's only a mesh but though Python it shows up as it was a solid (I even extrude the scan on pyvista).

Here you can see it.

[image]

Does anybody know how can I make this mesh a solid so I can print it?

[Here is the obj file for download](https://mediafire.com/file/h7wex1zmpod4gao/scan.obj/file)

Edit: [Scan without extrusion](https://mediafire.com/file/rl7buw1sl2gm0lg/scanwithoutextrusion.obj/file)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've tried using the SolidifyModifier(Modifier) from Blenderpy and tried to extrude it with Py-MADCAD instead of pymesh with no luck.

Comment: Then you can show us your code and explain what exactly did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, there was a bug in [pymadcad](https://github.com/jimy-byerley/pymadcad) for the .OBJ importation.
This is fixed in the latest source version and will be available in the next release.

However I think what you are looking for is not extrusion but thickening:
This is the result:

```py
thickscan = thicken(
              read('scan.obj'), 
              0.01,               # offset between surfaces
              method='point',     # 'point' if faster and fine for a higly resolved mesh like this, but leave it to default works also
              )
```

[image: thickened mesh]

**NB**

The extrusion function only works shifting by an offset vector, and not along the mesh normals, which is usually not good for closed shapes like this:

```py
thick = extrusion(vec3(0.01,0,0), read('scan.obj'))
```

[image]